# Swift Version 2 Bool

Tags: boolean, swift2, void

I'm having trouble with creating an app in Swift2.
The App has an image of a wolf which changes every 0.4 seconds to reveal a running wolf.

However I have Bool errors in Swift 2 that I cannot fix.
I also have issues with declaring a void function.
Any help would be appreciated.  [image]

```
    @IBAction func startRunnng(sender: UIButton)
    {
        tmrRun = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        btnGo.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        btnStop.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        sliSpeed.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }

    @IBAction func stopRunnng(sender: UIButton)
    {
        tmrRun invalidate()
        btnGo.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        btnStop.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        sliSpeed.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }

    void takeaBound
    {
        String *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"wolf%d.png", pic];self.imvWolf.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
            pic += 1;
            if (pic == 8)
            pic = 0;
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pic = 0;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: Thank you pbodsk.   I have made a few changes and I will look at the functions section on Swift2 guide.  I'll post any follow up issues I may have.  I have 3 errors remaining on my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boolean values in Swift are `true` and `false`, `YES` and `NO` is used in Objective C.

So in your `stopRunning` method for instance, you should write:

```
@IBAction func stopRunnng(sender: UIButton)
{
    tmrRun invalidate()
    btnGo.userInteractionEnabled = true
    btnStop.userInteractionEnabled = false
    sliSpeed.userInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

(sidenote, you don't need the `;` in Swift either)

About the void function. In Swift you write the return type AFTER your method declaration, starting with a `->`. Like so:

```
func takeABound(parametersWouldGoHere) -> ()
```

For a void method you can write `()` or `Void` or, as you'll often do, don't write anything at all.

```
func takeABound(parametersWouldGoHere)
```

As it says in "The Swift Programming Language" in the chapter about [functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158)

> Because it does not need to return a value, the function’s definition does not include the return arrow (->) or a return type.

You can read more about functions, booleans and the like in ["The Swift Programming Language"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html), there is a nice chapter called "A Swift Tour" that will introduce you to many of the basic things.

Hope that helps

Comment: I see what you mean and I understand the reasoning. But...If it was me who'd asked that question I would prefer a hint about which direction to even start looking and a recommendation about what to read instead of just a "Learn Swift". Yes he/she should have done some research before asking, but if you're just starting out learning something new you get confused about compiler messages and the like when you just want to see some seemingly simple thing work. So why not help him/her? Now the next time he (hopefully) knows where to look before asking. That's just the way I see it, sorry :-)